# Ancient sources for singing in a bath

Tags: classical-latin, reference-request

Years ago a fellow Latinist told me that singing in the shower is not a new invention.
He mentioned some ancient (Roman, I believe) writer mentioning that singing is convenient while bathing due to the echo amplifying and altering the voice.
I no longer remember the details, but I would like to locate such a text and verify this singing tradition for myself.
So, can anyone point me to a passage in ancient Roman literature about singing while bathing?

Comment: I found a 14th century reference to it from [Ibn Khaldun](http://www.muslimphilosophy.com/ik/Muqaddimah/Chapter1/Ch_1_04.htm), but no luck with classical sources so far...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found one reference!

### [Petronius, *Satyricon*, 73](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0001%3Atext%3DSatyricon%3Asection%3D73)

> Deinde ut lassatus consedit, **invitatus balnei sono diduxit usque ad cameramos ebrium et coepit Menecratis cantica lacerare**, sicut illi dicebant, qui linguam eius intellegebant.
>
> *He then became tired and sat down, and **the echoes of the bathroom encouraged him to open his tipsy jaws to the ceiling and begin to murder Menecrates's songs**, as I was told by those who could understand what he said.* (Heseltine's translation)

Comment: Brilliant! This may well be the passage I originally heard of.